# Необходимо в QWebEngineView открывать ссылки с _blank в той же окне. Как реализовать?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qwebengine

Необходимо чтобы ссылки (например в том же яндексе, которые по умолчанию открываются в новой вкладке) открывались в том же окне, подменяя существующую страницу (без новых вкладок) или просто как будто переход без **`_blank`**.

Реализую в `QWebEngineView`. Сам браузер расположен в `setCentralWidget`.

Вот часть моего кода:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://yandex.ru"))

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
```

В интернете нашёл решение, что необходимо прописать функцию:

```py
 def createWindow(self, wintype):
   return self
```

Но прописав её, всё равно не заработало. Как возможно реализовать такое? Спасибо!

Comment: Пробовал и у меня все вкладки открываются в том же окне. Можете подробнее рассказать про шаги? Функцию createWindow создавали в MainWindow или у наследника QWebEngineView (или QWebEnginePage)?

Comment: Да, в MainWindow. У меня класс один только.

Comment: Ну, так вы не там функцию создали: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#createWindow . И все-таки, про вашу проблему я так и не понял :) у меня в том же browser открываются новые ссылки, хотя могли бы в новой вкладке

Comment: Да я читал эту документацию. Все ссылки конечно открываются в той же вкладке. Но ссылки которые по умолчанию должны открыться в новой, например с яндекс поиска попробуйте перейти. Они пытаются открыть новую вкладку, а так как у меня нет функции под новую вкладку, не открываются и клик остаётся просто кликом и ничего не происходит. Если у вас есть готовое решение, не могли бы вы поделиться им?

Comment: Может в моём случае надо как то так сделать - self.browser.createWindow(self, wintype) ? добавить такую строку или так - self.browser.createWindow(self, QWebEnginePage)
 ... Но ошибку бъёт тогда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage


class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

    def createWindow(self, _type):
        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        page.urlChanged.connect(self.on_url_changed)
        return page

    @pyqtSlot(QUrl)
    def on_url_changed(self, url):
        page = self.sender()
        self.setUrl(url)
        page.deleteLater()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        page = WebEnginePage(self.browser)
        self.browser.setPage(page)
        self.browser.load(QUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, круть, работает :)

Comment: Если отдельно Ваш код запускаю то всё работает, но если встраиваю в своё приложение class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage): ** то почему то по той же ссылке для теста переход не осуществляется. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Всё разобрался, работает, надо было добавить просто

        page = WebEnginePage(self.browser)
        self.browser.setPage(page)

Не внимательность))

Comment: Уважаемый @SergeyNudnov я у вас насчёт асинхронности ничего не спрашивал. 
Я дал вариант решения на заданный вопрос. У вас приведенный мною пример не работает?
Если у вас есть другой вариант решения опубликуйте его как ответ на заданный вопрос.

Comment: Глюк попутал насчет конструкторов - всё верно, приношу свои извинения. А вот асинхронность стоит учитывать. Компенсировал свой глупый минус здесь, который я не могу почему-то отозвать - в других Ваших ветках.